# Running time analysis of Fibonacci algorithm.

Tags: algorithms, induction, computational-complexity, fibonacci-numbers, recursion

I am getting the following statement:

**Code**

```
RecFibo(n):
if (n < 2)
  return n
else
  return RecFibo(n − 1) + RecFibo(n − 2)
```

**From text:**

> Another way to see this is that the RecFibo is building a big binary
>   tree of additions, with nothing but zeros and ones at the leaves.
>   Since the eventual output is Fn , our algorithm must call RecRibo(1)
>   (which returns 1) exactly Fn times. A quick inductive argument implies
>   that RecFibo(0) is called exactly Fn−1 times. Thus, the recursion tree
>   has Fn + Fn−1 = Fn+1 leaves, and therefore, because it’s a full binary
>   tree, it must have 2Fn+1 − 1 nodes.

Further

> A quick inductive argument implies that RECFIBO(0) is called exactly
>   Fn−1 times. Thus, the recursion tree has Fn + Fn−1 = Fn+1 leaves, and
>   therefore, because it’s a full binary tree, it must have 2Fn+1 − 1
>   nodes.

Although I understand and can visualize the recursive tree but the induction analysis leaves me puzzled. My main confusion is the most obvious part from the author claiming **"our algorithm must call RecFibo(1) (which returns 1) exactly Fn times"** and same for **"RecFibo(0)"**.

**Reference:**

http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/05-dynprog.pdf

Comment: Run time and number of recursive calls are related, but not the same thing.  The size of the output of your fibonacci function increases exponentially, so the run time will be at least exponentially larger than the number of recursive calls.

Comment: You said "Since the eventual output is $F_n$ , our algorithm must call `RecRibo(1)` (which returns $1$) exactly $F_n$ times".  Now replace $n$ with $n-1$ to set up the inductive proof

Comment: @Henry that was quoted from the text not my statement, but let me try with pen and paper, also if you can give some insight that would be good.

Comment: @Henry I did some thinking and analyzed that since the values are `0` and `1` hence only `1` should be the contributing factor not `0` so, since `RicFibo(4) = 3` there must be three ones and that could be present only via call to `RicFibo(1)`, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Lets use the notation from your notes. So we define $T(n)$ as the number of recursive calls of $RecFib$. We first note that
$$T(0)=1 \text{ and } T(1)=1.$$
This is easy to see, since we fulfill the condition of the "if" and do not call the function $RecFib$ again.
Next we observe that for $n\ge 2$ $$T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1.$$
For this note that we once have to call the function itself and then since $n\ge 2$ we call the function $RecFib$ again but with inputs $n-1$ and $n-2$, contributing the terms $T(n-1)$ and $T(n-2)$.

**Claim:** $T(n)=2F_{n+1}-1$.

**Proof:** We proceed here by induction. The cases $n \in \{0,1\}$ should be clear. So lets assume the induction hypothesis holds for $n'$ with $0 \le n' <n$. Lets compute $T(n)$ using the induction hypothesis in the second equality: 
$$ T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)+1=(2F_n -1 )+ (2F_{n-1}-1)+1=2(F_n+F_{n-1})-1=2F_{n+1}-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

If (by the inductive hypothesis)

- in calculating `RecFibo(n-1)` you call `RecFibo(1)` $F_{n-1}$ times and `RecFibo(0)` $F_{n-2}$ times
- in calculating `RecFibo(n-2)` you call `RecFibo(1)` $F_{n-2}$ times and `RecFibo(0)` $F_{n-3}$ times

then in calculating `RecFibo(n)` by calling `RecFibo(n-1)` and `RecFibo(n-2)` you call `RecFibo(1)` $F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}=F_{n}$ times and `RecFibo(0)` $F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}=F_{n-1}$ times

You should probably also show the hypothesis is true for `RecFibo(2)` and either `RecFibo(3)` or `RecFibo(1)`

This is not the most efficient algorithm

Comment: "in calculating RecFibo(n-1) you call RecFibo(1) Fn−1Fn−1 times and RecFibo(0) Fn−2Fn−2 times" is not clear to me, can you please explain this, maybe I am not getting something obvious.